# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer python 3

Tags: python

I have a program that queries a REST API (Oanda) and it has been working fine throughout development (about a month or two). The following is how I am requesting my data:

```
import urllib.request
def getCandles( currency="EUR_USD", count=500, granularity="D"):

    headers = getHeader()
    base_url = 'https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/'
    ins_url = 'v3/instruments/{}/candles/?count={}&price=M&granularity={}'.format( currency, count, granularity)
    url = base_url + ins_url
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    response = json.loads( response.decode('utf-8') )
    return response['candles']
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_indicators.py", line 109, in <module>
    candles = getCandles()
  File "test_indicators.py", line 19, in getCandles
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1321, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1012, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 874, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I've searched the related questions but couldn't find an answer as a lot of them are using socket module and I am using request. I did seem to get the impression the error was something on my side, however, in writing this question I realized if I query https://www.oanda.com/account/ in my search bar I get a 500, so I am assuming that is what is returned to req. Does this mean the site I am querying has blocked me?

I am well under the request limits (1/sec of the 20/sec they allow), but last night I did exceed the limit of number of data points per request until I found 5000 was the maximum. But it worked fine when I ran it this morning.

Also, I am not spoofing my request as a previous SO answer requested and don't feel I need to as it's an API and has been working fine. In addition, I reset my token authorization on Oanda but still no luck. I guess my question is if this sounds like I have been blocked or is this something I can fix on my end or is it possible Oanda server is just down?

If it helps I am using Django 2.0 and python 3 on linux 16.02.

Thanks, and apologies if I didn't follow SO guidelines as this is my first question asked in quite awhile.

Comment: You mention manually querying  https:/www.oanda.com/account/, but that's not what your code is querying.  So why is that relevant?  -  The only advice I can think to give is to first make sure you're testing the same URL manually that your code is using, and then try it in as many places as possible...like log onto an AWS server and try it if you've got anything running in 'AWS, or ask a friend or relative to try it.  Or maybe just wait a while first to see if the site really is down and comes back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use requests library in python.For which you can read over here `http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/`.
Secondly I tried to make a get request to the URL you had mentioned and i got a `401 - UnAuthorized` as the response. The reason being that I do not have the headers.
If you want you can use the following piece of code i modified for you.

```
import requests
def getCandles( currency="EUR_USD", count=500, granularity="D"):

    headers = getHeader()
    base_url = 'https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/'
    ins_url = 'v3/instruments/{}/candles/?count={}&price=M&granularity={}'.format( currency, count, granularity)
    url = base_url + ins_url
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
       return response.json().get('candles')
    else:
        return None
```

Another thing which can should do is check for the status 200.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Interestingly, I can go to the url in my search bar as well, but the old code still doesn't work. But I will refactor to use requests. Tried to upvote but says it won't display

Comment: Well you can accept it as answer anyways, that works as well.