# Urllib2 suddenly not working. Requesting time

Tags: python, time, connection, urllib2

So I got this application which uses urllib2 for requesting time from the internet as follows:

```py
request = urllib2.Request('https://time.gov/actualtime.cgi')
  try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    raw_time = response.read()
  except:
    #return failure in code, break of code.
```

It has been working perfectly fine for almost a full year, but a month ago it suddenly stopped working. (Both at home, on my work and on two different computers.) (Forgot to save the stacktrace.) Anyway, one month forward (to today), it works perfectly fine again without having to change anything in the code! (Although I've implemented a fallback method now incase it happens again.)

I'm curious as what could have caused this. Anybody has any ideas? Insights?

note: Not 100% certain about the following but quite certain.
So another application used the exact same code (but without the try, except statement) and still kept working? How is that even possible?

Edit: Website "https://time.gov/actualtime.cgi" wasn't down. Checked it via my browser and responded as normal.

Comment: Could it just be that the website `https://time.gov/actualtime.cgi` went down?

Comment: Forgot to metion that. Checked the website via my internet browser and it wasn't down. Still responded as normal. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: You can try a solution given to me when the Request library was giving me problems. But yesterday it kept giving me an error after months of it working fine, but this morning it is working again. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838957/connectionreseterror-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer-python-3]